# Substitution in right side of statement

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to programmatically determine the parent of each widget in my python/kv project.
I have successfully created label, textinput, float, etc. widgets and hoped I could do something like

```
xxx=['.','.l.','.t.','.f.','.b1.','.b2.','.l3.','.s.','.l2.']
for i in xxx:
    xi=f'xparent=self.ids{i}parent'
    exec('xi')
    print(xi)
    print(xparent)


where the items in xxx are the kv id's

The exec() treats xi like a literal not a command to execute

Output: xparent=self.ids.parent  <-- from print(xi) 

     print(xparent)
           ^^^^^^^
 UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'xparent' where it is not associated with a value



If I remove print(xparent)

I get

xparent=self.ids.parent
xparent=self.ids.l.parent
xparent=self.ids.t.parent
xparent=self.ids.f.parent
xparent=self.ids.b1.parent
xparent=self.ids.b2.parent
xparent=self.ids.l3.parent
xparent=self.ids.s.parent
xparent=self.ids.l2.parent
```

Comment: Why are you using such a complex approach as opposed to just using the `parent` property of every widget?